# Extracting JSON Data -

Tags: arrays, json, swift, nsdictionary, fbsdk

I have the following JSON data structure being pulled from FBSDKGraphRequest.

```
data =     (
            {
        id = "<USER_ID_GOES_HERE>";
        name = "Tom Jones";
        picture =             {
            data =                 {
                "is_silhouette" = 0;
                url = "<USER_IMAGE_URL_GOES_HERE>";
            };
        };
    },
            {
        id = "<USER_ID_GOES_HERE>";
        name = "Tom Jones";
        picture =             {
            data =                 {
                "is_silhouette" = 0;
                url = "<USER_IMAGE_URL_GOES_HERE>";
            };
        };
    },
            {
        id = "<USER_ID_GOES_HERE>";
        name = "Tom Jones";
        picture =             {
            data =                 {
                "is_silhouette" = 0;
                url = "<USER_IMAGE_URL_GOES_HERE>";
            };
        };
    },
```

I want to extract the data and place it into an array.  I am having difficulty with the first "data" key.

Heres my FBSDKGR:

```
let params = ["fields": "name, picture.type(large)"]
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: params)
    request!.start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("There is some error getting friends", error!)
        }
        else if result != nil {
            print("Here is the result", result!)
```

Comment: essentially I want to get this data into a UITableView

Comment: Did you search on SO? There are hundreds of related questions to parse JSON. Read the JSON! `[]` are arrays (to be subscripted by index) `{}` are dictionaries  (to be subscripted by key). However the listing is a console output of a Swift collection type. There `()` are arrays and `{}` are dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

[With an extra dependency, if you don't mind.](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
import SwiftyJSON

let json = JSON(result) // after you get result from FBSDKGR
let data = json["data"].array
for (index, _) in data.enumerated() {
     if let id = json["data", index, "id"].int {
          // add to your array
          if let name = json["data", index, "name"].string {
              // continue nesting...
         }
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your JSOND dta is array of dictionary so , we can cast the result by the following way . First of all we will take two array , one is for names list and other is for picture details . here picture details array is array of dictionary . let's go for code

```
var namesArray = [String]()
var ImageDetailsArrayDict= [[String :AnyObject]]()

let params = ["fields": "name, picture.type(large)"]
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: params)
    request!.start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("There is some error getting friends", error!)
        }
        else if result != nil {
            print("Here is the result", result!)
         if let response = result["data"] as? [[String :AnyObject]] {

               for i in 0..<response.count {
                  namesArray.append(response[i]["name"] as! String)                
                  ImageDetailsArrayDict.append(response[i]["picture"])

                 }
              }
          }
      }
```

Now , we have two array . so we can easily populate it in the tableView .
   Good luck .

Comment: there is still an error type any has no subscript members on:

    if let response = result["data"] as? [[String :AnyObject]] {